# FilenameFilter not filtering zip files - Java

Tags: java

I'm implementing a `ZipComparison` file, which traverses a directory tree structure, and processes the `MD5` of all the `.zip` files in that directory tree structure.

```
import java.io.*;

public class ZipComparison {

public class ZipFilenameFilter implements FilenameFilter {

    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        if( name != null &&
                ( dir.isDirectory() || name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".zip"))) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
/**
 * These two constant values are the root for the directory
 */
private static final String root_a = "D:/UDU/r/tc10.0.0.2012080100_A";
private static final String root_b = "D:/UDU/r/tc10.0.0.2012080100_B";
private ZipFilenameFilter filter;

public ZipComparison() {
     this.filter = new ZipFilenameFilter();
}

public void matchMD5() {
    try{
        File root = new File( ZipComparison.root_a );
        if( !root.exists() ){
            System.out.println( "root doesn't exist" );
        }
        else if( !root.isDirectory() ) {
            System.out.println( "root isn't a directory" );
        }
        else{

            File[] files = new File( ZipComparison.root_a ).listFiles( this.filter );

            if( files != null ){
                showFiles( files );
            }
            else{
                System.out.println( "List of files was null." );
                System.exit( -1 );
            }
        }
    }
    catch(SecurityException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * iterates over the directory tree structure.
 * @param files
 */
public void showFiles( File[] files ){
    for( File file : files ){
        if( file.isDirectory() ) {
            System.out.println( "Directory: " + file.getName() );
            showFiles( file.listFiles( this.filter ) );
        }
        else {
            System.out.println( "File: " + file.getName() );
        }
    }
}
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ZipComparison zc = new ZipComparison();
    zc.matchMD5();

    System.exit( 0 );
}
```

}

When I execute the program without the `ZipFilenameFilter filter` it works just fine. However, when I add the `filter` to the

```
File[] files = new File( ZipComparison.root_a ).listFiles( filter );
```

nothing is getting printed out. Am I missing something?

Comment: It looks like it is testing the directory name to end with .zip?

Comment: @TylerHeiks I've updated my question, please take a look.

Comment: @philippe Please edit the code so it's correct; as it is you have an empty class and a class-within-a-class.

Comment: @DaveNewton I've updated with the latest code I have. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A couple of things. First, you need the filter for the recursive call, not just the first one. Second, the `dir` passed in to the filter will always be a dir, because it's a dir. That's not what the answer said to do. Although the answer is wrong too, because you can't call `isDirectory` on a string.

Comment: @DaveNewton I had updated to reflect the `filter` in the recursive call. I'm not understanding when you mentioned: "Second, the dir passed in to the filter will always be a dir, because it's a dir. That's not what the answer said to do"

Comment: @philippe Your updated code originally had `name.isDirectory()`. But the `directory` argument passed in to match is *always* a directory, so that will *always* be true, hence you're no longer filtering for zip files or directories. You need to see if the dir + name is a dir.

Comment: @DaveNewton Could you publish your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two main issues:

1. The filter needs to check to see if the current path (dir **+** file) is a directory, and
2. The zip filter needs to be applied in the recursive function as well, not just the first one.

Filter:

```java
public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
    if (name == null) {
        return false;
    }

    return new File(dir, name).isDirectory() || name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".zip");
}
```

Recursive function (assuming a class variable zip filter):

```java
public void showFiles(File[] files) {
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("Directory: " + file.getName());
            showFiles(file.listFiles(zipFilenameFilter));
        } else {
            System.out.println("File: " + file.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you are search recursive but filtered dir by mistake.
Try

```
if( name != null &&(name.isDirectory()||
                name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".zip")))
```

Comment: I updated my answer, but now I'm seeing all the files regardless they end with `.zip`

Comment: @philippe You need to apply the filter for the recursive `listFiles` as well.

Comment: @DaveNewton I added the filter to the recursive `listFiles`, but the outcome is the same. :-(

Comment: @Ted `name` is a string, and has no `isDirectory` method. The `File` passed in to `accept` is *always* a directory, however, so that condition will always be true. What's required is to check dir + name to see if it's a directory.

Answer (score 2):

Your filtered `listFiles` call will list *only* zip files. It will exclude subdirectories, so you will only see zip files that are directly within the root, not those that are deeper down the tree. You probably want a `FileFilter` that accepts all directories, plus any non-directories whose name ends in `.zip`.

Comment: I updated my question, but I'm seeing all the files regardless they end with `.zip`.